# How to place AdMob Native Advanced Ads in RecyclerView Android using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, admob, google-native-ads

There are many questions asked here but I couldn't find appropriate answer.

I would like to show native ads in my RecyclerView after every 5 items is displayed. If you got full steps I will appreciate it.

Anyone with full step of the code integration is very helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to show native ads in position after every 5 items.
First you need the code to create the ad, if you can't display it yet, please refer to [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start)

Next create layout for native ads similar to creating items of Recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#282750"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/s_1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView
                android:id="@+id/mv_ads"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/s_5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>

in recyclerview you want to display please add code

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    context = parent.getContext();
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
        return new Main2ViewHolder(
                ItemMain2Binding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        parent,
                        false
                )
        );
    } else  {
        return new NativeAdsViewHolder(
                ItemNativeAdsBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        parent,
                        false
                )
        );
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
        Main2ViewHolder itemHolder = (Main2ViewHolder) holder;
        itemHolder.setData(list.get(position));
        itemHolder.binding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(v -> {
            listener.click(list.get(position));
        });
    }
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_NATIVE_ADS) {
        NativeAdsViewHolder adsViewHolder = (NativeAdsViewHolder) holder;
        adsViewHolder.setData();
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType;
    if (position == 5) {
        viewType = VIEW_TYPE_NATIVE_ADS;
    }else {
        viewType = VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }
    return viewType;
}
```

Finally, make sure in your list, for every 5th position, you add any value, so that it replaces the position of the ad.